# What does this variable point with regard to malloc?

Tags: c, pointers

currently i'm learning about pointers.

```
   mat3 = (double***) malloc(m*sizeof(double**));
```

This statement indicates that mat3 points to the first array of the two arrays that contain double**.

```
mat3[0] = (double**) malloc(m*n*sizeof(double*));
```

I made a small figure to show how I see this. I don't understand why the line with the comment is wrong. In my opinion the same happens as the one above.

```
   for (i=0; i<m; i++)
   {
      mat3[i] = mat3[0] + i*n;
      for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
         mat3[i][j] = mat3[i][0] + j*p; // this goes wrong
      }
   }
```

In the first loop the adress of the first ** array taken and each iteration 3 is added. The figure also shows that there are 3 * arrays, so that looks OK.

In the second loop the adress of the first * array is taken and each iteration 4 is added. That also looks okay since each * array contains 4 places to store a double. So 4 memory places needs to be skipped.

There is something wrong, but I don't see it. Can I get feedback?

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   double*** mat3;
   int m,n,p;
   int i,j,k;
   
   m=2; n=3; p=4;

   printf("This program causes a coredump, unless you fix the error in it !\n");
   
   mat3 = (double***) malloc(m*sizeof(double**));
   if (mat3 == NULL)
      exit(1);
   
   mat3[0] = (double**) malloc(m*n*sizeof(double*));
   if (mat3[0] == NULL)
      exit(1);
   
   mat3[0][0] = (double*) malloc(m*n*p*sizeof(double));
   if (mat3[0][0] == NULL)
      exit(1);
   
   for (i=0; i<m; i++)
   {
      mat3[i] = mat3[0] + i*n;
      for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
         mat3[i][j] = mat3[i][0] + j*p; // this goes wrong
      }
   }
   
   for(i=0;i<m;i++)
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
         for(k=0;k<p;k++)
             mat3[i][j][k] = i + 10*j + 100*k;
   
   for(i=0;i<m;i++)
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
         for(k=0;k<p;k++)
             printf("mat3[%d][%d][%d] = %lf\n",i,j,k,mat3[i][j][k]);
   
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you know that this line is the problem?

Comment: Why do you use `int` as an array index? Why do you not use `size_t`?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123  This is an assignment and the comment was part of the assignment

Comment: Consider this: What is the value of `mat3[i][0]` ?

Comment: @4386427 The value of mat3[i][0] is the adress of the whole array of 4 right? The * array

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Terr070 And what if `i` isn't zero? Like `mat3[1][0]`

Comment: @4386427 Should in the in the first loop n be changed with m and in the second loop p be changed with n?

Comment: Draw a diagram, which pointer points to which array of pointers where each pointer point to which object and so on. Think about when each pointer is initialized with which value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a diagram of what you are trying to create:

[image]

The green arrows show the 3 pointers that was initialized using the `malloc` calls.

The red arrows show the 6 pointers that has not been initialized at this point.

So the code after the 3 `malloc` must initialize all the red pointers before using them. And your code doesn't do that.

The line `mat3[i] = mat3[0] + i*n;` will initialize `mat3[1]`.

Then the line `mat3[i][j] = mat3[i][0] + j*p;` uses `mat3[0][0]` and `mat3[1][0]` on the rigth hand side. Use of `mat3[0][0]` is fine as it has been initialized but use of `mat3[1][0]` is bad as it's uninitialized.

Change

```
mat3[i][j] = mat3[i][0] + j*p;
```

to

```
mat3[i][j] = mat3[0][0] + i*n*p + j*p;
```

Comment: Really helpful! Thanks for taking time to make a figure!

Comment: You are correct, but i am not sure if you should just present the right answer for such a question. Since he is still learning it would probably better to only say how he can find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how each pointer is initialized and which pointer points to which object.

Start like this. After  `mat3 =  malloc(m*sizeof(double**));` ,`mat3` points to an array of length 6 with the elements pointer to pointer to `double`.

```
 mat3 (double ***)
   |
   V
+----+----+
|    |    |   (double **) //uninitialized
+----+----+
```

After the next `malloc()`, there is a different situation.

```
  mat3 (double ***)
   |
   V
+----+----+
|    |    | (double **) //uninitialized except element 0
+----+----+
   |
   V
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |  (double *) //uninitialized
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Continue this diagram and draw one for each change (just the principle, no need to draw all 24 boxes for the 24 `double`). When a pointer is set to a wrong value, you know where the error is and how to fix it.
I know where the problem is, after i thought about it for a while, and how to fix it, but you should learn to solve this problem on your own.

Off-Topic: Array indexes should never be of type `int`, use `size_t` for positive values or `ptrdiff_t` when you need code that also works with negative indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but

`sizeof(double*),
sizeof(double**),
sizeof(double***),
sizeof(double****)`

...,
return the same number of bytes( size of the memory address supported).

Comment: To start with: It is not the intension that you ask a question by writing it in an answer to another question. Please post it as a new question. But in short: You are wrong.

Comment: @4386427, please tell me more about it.

Comment: About what? How to ask a new question?

Comment: This is true on most machines but completely irrelevant for the question.